# SQL Trigger to add data from other table if there is an entry match

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've got two tables one:

```
ID | TimeStamp | Data
---|-----------|------ 
1  | 10/10/2015| 54
2  | 11/10/2015| 493
3  | 12/10/2015| 293
```

and the other:

```
ID | Interval | Location
---|----------|------ 
1  | 23       | New York
2  | 22       | London
3  | 21       | Paris
```

I would like to have an `SQL trigger` that executes when a new entry is added to the first table. The `trigger` would then combine the data from both tables into another table... something like this:

```
ID | TimeStamp | Data | Interval | Location
---|-----------|------|----------|------ 
1  | 10/10/2015|    54| 23       | New York
2  | 11/10/2015|   493| 22       | London
3  | 12/10/2015|   293| 21       | Paris
```

I'm new to `SQL`, and have looked into both triggers and join requests. If someone could point me into the right direction to write a query it would be amazing.

Comment: Well how does your trigger for data from single table looks like then?

Comment: You might reconsider your application design. I'd generally advise to not store the combined table, but instead write a view that returns the combined view on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way to go in this case would be to use join (either as a query or create a view), it sounds like using a trigger and keeping the data twice is redundant.

The join here is quite simple, just inner join on the ID field:

```
SELECT f.ID, f.timestamp, f.data, second.location, second.interval from
  firstTable as f inner join secondTable as s on f.ID = s.ID;
```

If you want it as a view, simply do:

```
CREATE VIEW joinView AS
SELECT f.ID, f.timestamp, f.data, second.location, second.interval from
  firstTable as f inner join secondTable as s on f.ID = s.ID;
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! Would there be a way to make this join query fire when a new entry comes into the first table? Or does this happen automatically?

Comment: nothing has to happen when new data is entered, that's the idea of views - the view query is executed whenever the view is queried, so the results we be whatever is in the tables on that moment